# Golint: some issues can detect by VSCode but not command line

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, golint

There are many lint issues that VSCode, which uses Golint behind can detect but the command-line version of `golint` cannot. Hence CI/CD tools cannot detect all issues. For example the following code:

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
```

VSCode will have the warning:

> the cancel function returned by context.WithTimeout should be called,
>   not discarded, to avoid a context leak

But when I run the command-line version of Golint, it cannot detect. I wonder if Golint has some configurations behind but found none.

Comment: Which linter are you using from VS Code? And with which options? Execute the same from the command line, and you should have the same result.

Comment: VSCode uses golint (as I mentioned in the post). I use the default configuration, and after I check, I see it uses no flag.

Comment: VSCode uses whatever you configure it to use. I'm asking how you have it configured. I always use golangci-lint both in VS Code, and on the command line, for instance.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks. I mean I have set up it using golint (and it is the default setting actually). And I don't change anything (implicit means there is no special flags as I checked). Hopefully I can get the command line that VSCode uses to run so I can debug that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message comes from [`golangci/govet`](https://github.com/golangci/govet/blob/54e733a64097854cf4d8fa80ccf48012a487ae1a/lostcancel.go#L78-L80), one of the activated by default linters of [`golangci/golangci-lint`](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#enabled-by-default-linters).

> I mean I have set up it using golint

This is different from [golint (golang/lint)](https://github.com/golang/lint), which does not include that check.

Comment: Thanks. That is correct. After I try to run govet I have the same error. However, I wonder what settings in VSCode that it uses govet. I cannot find. (or this is the default anyway).

Comment: @TrầnKimDự It would be run automatically if the linter is golangcli, and not gocli.

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Check if your linter is actually golangci-lint, and disable in a config file (https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint#config-file) govet.